# How to install eclipse for java developer,c/c++ developer, php developer at the same time?

Tags: java, php, javascript, eclipse

Now I am trying to install eclipse on my computer under Windows 7. The problem is how to install the eclipse for java,c/c++,php,javascript concurrently?

Would donwloading the four zip files and then unziping them all into one directly say `d:\eclipse` works?
Is there any good tutorials for installation/configuration of eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download all the zip directory and unzip it in the same folder (e.g. `ECLIPSE_HOME`) and run eclipse. Eclipse will first inspect it 'plugins', 'features` folders and update configurations for future use.

Alternatively, you can download the main eclipse (Simple Eclipse for Java SE) and goto `Help` --> `Install New Software` menu and select the C++ packages (and all relevant packages) you need and install.

Answer (score 9):

The zips are just pre-bundled archives of Eclipse plus the relevant plug-ins. Just pick one, install it, then use **Help | Install New Software** to add the other plug-ins you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could either download eclipse for one of the languages and then download plugins for that one or you could download the four separate zips and unzip them to the same PARENT folder!

Like:

```
/Eclipse/Java
/Eclipse/C
/Eclipse/Cpp
/Eclipse/Php
```

I'm not sure what would happen if you'd unzip them to the same folder, but I would dissuade it. By unzipping them to a separate folder you can launch a specific eclipse installation for one of the views, so you won't have to switch views.

Also, I remember that having one eclipse version with multiple plugins tends to make eclipse messy (at least at the time when I was using it, more or less a year ago)